# After updating to Catalina and zsh some LaunchAgents won't run

Tags: macos, zsh, macos-catalina

Before the update my LaunchAgents were synchronising files to my git server around 3 am. The agent runs a script called gitSync.sh, a bash script.
I did remove the !#/bin/bash in the script.
I am using the map ~/Library.LaunchAgents under my own name and 644.

I can execute the script by hand.

Loading the agent gives: gitSync.plist: Path had bad ownership/permissions
Changing the ownership to root:staff takes the error message away, but the script which normally executes after loading does not run.

Catalina is strict! You have to give explicitly rights to your shell(s) in Security & Privacy!
When you give your shell enough rights, the agent(s) will run again.